# Azure API Management - apply policy only if tag is set

Tags: azure-api-management

I managed to configure in APIM a set of policies that do what I need (authentication). The config XML is long and dirty, but the rules should be applied to all APIs that require authentication, so I can just set them on 'All APIs' level. But of course not all APIs require authentication. The idea is to configure them using some kind of flow control policy so that they are applied only if API is tagged. But I didn't found a way how to get the APIs metadata.

So is there a way the read APIs metadata using APIM expressions? Or any other way to achieve the main goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions#ContextVariables again I see no way to query tag meta information while in a policy. Of course you could query tags for an API over API Management REST API itself on the way but I guess this would increase latency substantially.

For cases like this I would create an API product, put the authentication part into the product's policy and then only assign relevant APIs to this product.

Comment: Thanks Kai, seems like the good workaround idea. But it seems I need to place a feature request there...